# How to use progressbar to count by end of day instead of beginning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, progress-bar

Right now the progressbar counts for the beginning of each day. For example,

[image]

The number shown is "1", but it still should say "0" since its the start of the first day. By the end of the day, 11:59pm, it should say "1" since by that time the habit would have been completed.

**habits/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10" style="width: <%= challenged.progress_in_percent %>%;">
    <%= challenged.calculate_days_lost %>
  </div> 
  <%= challenged.days_left_in_current_level %>
</div>
```

**habit.rb**

```
 def real_missed_days
     value = 0
     levels.each do |level|
         value += level.missed_days + level.days_lost
     end
     value
  end

  def calculate_days_lost
      def n_days
        ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count do |date| 
          committed_wdays.include? date.wday
        end - self.real_missed_days
      end     

   case n_days    
      when 0..9
        n_days
      when 10..24
        n_days-10
      when 25..44
        n_days-25
      when 45..69
        n_days-45
      when 70..99
        n_days-70
      else
        n_days-100
    end
  end

    def days_left_in_current_level
        def n_days
            ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count do |date|
                committed_wdays.include? date.wday
            end - self.real_missed_days
        end

        case n_days
          when 0..9
            10-n_days
          when 10..24
            25-n_days
          when 25..44
            45-n_days
          when 45..69
            70-n_days
          when 70..99
            100-n_days
          else
            0 # No end
        end
    end
```

Here's the **[Gist](https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2)** of it.

Please let me know if I should provide further code or explanation :]

Comment: Can you add some more explanation about what you are trying to do?  Imagine that nobody else know what you mean by "since I just started the habit today" for example.

Comment: Sorry @MaxWilliams hopefully my rewording will make more sense of it. Ultimately the progressbar moves up 1 at the start of the day instead of at the end, which is what I'd prefer if possible :]

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to change at 11.59 pm instead of midnight?

Comment: @MaxWilliams doesn't matter so long as it's end of day instead of the beginning. For example, when I log onto my web app in the morning the progressbar would count today as if I already did the habit, but I don't want the progressbar to count today. I want it to only count yesterday and days prior. So in the example above the bar shows "1" but it should still say "0" because I just started that habit today then by tomorrow it should move up by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In habit.rb I changed any mentioning of the method `.today` to `.yesterday`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite confusing but if you want to know how many days, as an integer, it is between when the task (or whatever it is) started and today, then just do

```
(Date.today - date_started.to_date).to_i
```

Comment: Thanks Max it turned out to be a very simple solution that I added in the answers